# Please help me find right namespace combination so I can query XML in C#

Tags: c#, xml, xml-parsing, xml-namespaces

I have one xml file whic I need to edit, It looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<PaketniUvozObrazaca xmlns="urn:PaketniUvozObrazaca_V1_0.xsd">
  <PodaciOPoslodavcu>
    <JIBPoslodavca>XXXXXXXXXX</JIBPoslodavca>
    <NazivPoslodavca>Comapyn</NazivPoslodavca>
    <BrojZahtjeva>1307</BrojZahtjeva>
    <DatumPodnosenja>2013-03-19</DatumPodnosenja>
  </PodaciOPoslodavcu>
  <Obrazac1022>
    <Dio1PodaciOPoslodavcuIPoreznomObvezniku>
      <JIBJMBPoslodavca>XXXXXXXXXX</JIBJMBPoslodavca>
      <Naziv>Compyny</Naziv>
      <AdresaSjedista>Adress </AdresaSjedista>
      <JMBZaposlenika>XXXXXXX</JMBZaposlenika>
      <ImeIPrezime>ad</ImeIPrezime>
      <AdresaPrebivalista>City</AdresaPrebivalista>
      <PoreznaGodina>2012</PoreznaGodina>
    </Dio1PodaciOPoslodavcuIPoreznomObvezniku>
</Obrazac1022>
</PaketniUvozObrazaca>
```

If i want to query (select nodes) from this file how I should reffernce namespace ?

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XmlDocument gip = new XmlDocument();
            gip.Load("C:\\vs2013tests\\adoGipko\\gip-2012.xml");

            XmlNamespaceManager nspm = new XmlNamespaceManager(gip.NameTable);
            nspm.AddNamespace("urn", "PaketniUvozObrazaca_V1_0");

            foreach (XmlNode uposlnik in gip.SelectNodes("//PaketniUvozObrazaca_V1_0/Obrazac1022", nspm))
            {
                Console.WriteLine(uposlnik.SelectSingleNode("Dio1PodaciOPoslodavcuIPoreznomObvezniku/ImeIPrezime",nspm).InnerText);

            }

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to give the namespace a name and specify the uri exactly as in the XML. Which name you use is not important:

```
nspm.AddNamespace("d", "urn:PaketniUvozObrazaca_V1_0.xsd");
```

You now have to use that name for all the tags:

```
foreach (XmlNode uposlnik in gip.SelectNodes("//d:PaketniUvozObrazaca/"+
                                             "d:Obrazac1022", nspm))
{
    Console.WriteLine(
        uposlnik.SelectSingleNode("d:Dio1PodaciOPoslodavcuIPoreznomObvezniku/"+
                                  "d:ImeIPrezime", nspm).InnerText);
}
```

Furthermore, I fixed the root tag in the query. You used `PaketniUvozObrazaca_V1_0` which is part of the namespace. You need to use `PaketniUvozObrazaca`, which is the root tag.

Comment: +1 for "Which name you use is not important:". Specifically, the namespace tag in your XPath *does not have to match* what was in the source XML text, only the *namespace uri* needs to match. This the main source of confusion for almost everyone that needs this.